# How open URL from EventHandler - ItemAdded [SharePoint 2010]

Tags: list, url, sharepoint-2010, event-handling

How can I open URL link to SharePoint list from EventHandler - ItemAdded ?
I tried: SPUtility.Redirect, properties.RedirectUrl but it doesn't work, mayby I do something wrong. Please help.

Thanks,
Luk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if you still having the same issue. 
Anyways the following link might help someone.

http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/06/redirection-from-event-handler.html

This page, however, does not properly explain how httpcontext works

```
public class **CustomEventReceiver** : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    private HttpContext _currentContext = null;

    public CustomEventReceiver () : base ()
    {
        if (null != HttpContext.Current)
        {
            _currentContext = HttpContext.Current
        }
    }

    public override void ItemAdding (SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
       // Here one can use _currentContext and redirect ...
    }
}
```

Should keep in mind that class names must match in order to get httpcontext.

This code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution: http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/06/redirection-from-event-handler.html

Comment: This is will require switching the event handler from ItemAdded to ItemAdding.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work ;( I use:  SPUtility.Redirect("http://xxxx:xx/sites/xxx/Lists/test/AllItems.aspx", SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, HttpContext.Current); ` and I had a comunicat NullrefereceException